# Exceute non query InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-handling

I'm trying to connect to sql server but I have this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and
>   available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method,
>   Boolean async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   FattureServer.Form1.button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

```
string dbserver2 = textBox4.Text;
string dbname2 = textBox1.Text;
string dbusername2 = textBox2.Text;
string dbpassword2 = textBox3.Text;


SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + dbserver + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + dbusername + ";Password=" + dbpassword + "");

// SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Cliente (IdCliente,IdUtente,RagioneSociale,Titolo,Indirizzo,Stato,Provincia,Citta,Comune,Cap,Telefono,Email) VALUES(@idcliente,@username,@password, @email)", conn2);

string query2 = "INSERT INTO Cliente (Titolo,RagioneSociale) VALUES(@Titolo,@RagioneSociale)";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query2, conn2);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titolo", titolo);

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RagioneSociale", ragionesociale);

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn2.Close();
```

how can solve this error?

**EDIT:**

if i insert conn2.open() i have this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Cliente'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at FattureServer.Form1.button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\riccardo\Desktop\FattureServer\FattureServer\Form1.cs:line 189 ClientConnectionId:02db8bd4-e91a-4b43-9ba9-e1717c9e96de Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16

Comment: you forgot to do a conn2.Open(); before executing the command.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed" ? Really?

Comment: Where do you open your connection? A connection is disposable. You should encapsulate your call in a "using".

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to do a conn2.Open(); before executing the command.

Edit. David Brabant is correct...you should be wrapping everything in a using statement.

Edit 2. It looks like your table "Cliente" is created in the DB. Are you sure you're pointing to the right database and that the table already exists?

Answer (score 2):

> Invalid object name 'Cliente'

That is another question.
Perhaps, a typo. Client? Check your data objects to avoid typos.

Comment: Rest of the table looks to be Italian. So `Cliente` would be correct. `IdCliente,IdUtente,RagioneSociale,Titolo,Indirizzo,Stato,Provincia,Citta,Comune,Cap,Telefono,Email`

Comment: Yes, have seen it. But he could check it out to be sure.